# Getting Internal Self-Test Error

Tags: warning-messages, fonts

I have two questions related to this simple code:

```
CDFDeploy[SystemDialogInput["FileSave"], 
  Panel[Row[{Button[Text[Style["sav", FontSize -> Scaled[.2]]],ImageSize -> Scaled[.2]], 
      Button[Text[Style["save", FontSize -> Scaled[.2]]],ImageSize -> Scaled[.2]]}],
      ImageSize -> Scaled[2]], WindowSize -> Scaled[2]]
```

1. Sometimes, I am getting `Internal Self-Test Error`. Why?
2. I am able to scale `Button` size, `Fontsize` and `Panel`size in the Horizontal direction but not 
   in the vertical direction. How to do this?

Comment: Have you tried multiple arguments for `Scaled`? -- `Scaled[{x,y}]`?

Comment: @kale: Yes, I have tried that too. Not working.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to deployment to CDF. I get the same error when I cut away the deploy stuff. It is intermittent. The code number is NoteFont2-c-1883

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: Yes, I have edited.

Comment: I can now reproduce it using the Panel part only. You need a new kernel *and* a new frontend to get this message (so a complete restart of Mathematica). The complete message is: "INTERNAL SELF-TEST ERROR: NoteFont2|c|1883
Click here to find out if this problem is known, and to help improve
Mathematica by reporting it to Wolfram Research." I clicked on the link and reported the problem.

Comment: The `Scaled` manual page: *Scaled can be used to specify scaled coordinates in any two- or three-dimensional graphics primitive.* and *You can use Scaled to represent objects that occupy a fixed region in a plot, independent of the specific range of coordinates in the plot.* So, you can't use `Scaled` everywhere.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: Ok, so what should I use instead of this?

Comment: The error seems to be related to the use of `Scaled` too. Remove it from the `ImageSize` options and the error is gone. Can you live with absolute quantities? `ImageSize -> {100, 200}` just works.

Comment: Yes, but I want all buttons, font on buttons and panel should resize with window resizing.

Comment: @Sjoerd I've edited your comments into an answer so that this Q has one. Hope that you don't mind.

Comment: @IstvánZachar No, I don't mind at all. Have been busy doing precisely that for two days after rm-rf's latest rally call.

Comment: @Sjoerd Same here, pity there is no badge for digging up the *oldest* skeleton in the grave... :)

Answer (score 1):

(Based on Sjoerd's comments)

It is reproducible using the `Panel` part only. You need a new kernel **and** a new frontend to get this message (so a complete restart of *Mathematica*). The complete message is:

> INTERNAL SELF-TEST ERROR: NoteFont2|c|1883 Click here to find out if this problem is known, and to help improve *Mathematica* by reporting it to Wolfram Research.

I clicked on the link and reported the problem.

The error seems to be related to the use of `Scaled`. The `Scaled` manual page states

> `Scaled` can be used to specify scaled coordinates in any two- or three-dimensional graphics primitive.
>
> You can use `Scaled` to represent objects that occupy a fixed region in a plot, independent of the specific range of coordinates in the plot.

So, you can't use `Scaled` everywhere. Remove `Scaled` from the `ImageSize` options and the error is gone. Can you live with absolute quantities? `ImageSize -> {100, 200}` just works.